# H2 database duplicate row when joining table

Tags: sql, h2

In H2 database SQL Without joining a table the following query output one row:

```
SELECT NAME as Product,DATE,RATE,QTY FROM BILL WHERE DATE LIKE '%9-10-2016'
```

[image]

But in H2 database when joining another it output extra 3 rows :

```
select BILL.NAME as product,
       COMPANY.NAME AS Company,
       BILL.DATE as ddate,
       BILL.RATE as rate,
       BILL.QTY as quantity 
FROM BILL INNER JOIN COMPANY ON BILL.DATE LIKE '%9-10-2016'
```

[image]

NOTE THAT - The column "COMPANY" select random name from that database for the duplication rows.

What's wrong am i doing here? I think the problem is with the join table. But can't figure it out myself!

**UPDATE:**
Perhaps i am missing another table to join that is called "ITEM" from where the "BILL.NAME" data is inserted . In "ITEM" Table has a column called "COMPANY_ID" that referenced to "COMPANY" table "ID" column.

Here is my new IDEA of the query but with same results:

```
select BILL.NAME as product,
   COMPANY.NAME AS Company,
   BILL.DATE as ddate,
   BILL.RATE as rate,
   BILL.QTY as quantity FROM BILL INNER JOIN COMPANY ON COMPANY.ID=ITEMS.COMPANY_ID INNER JOIN ITEMS WHERE BILL.DATE LIKE '%9-10-2016';
```

In the database i have 3 Table 
1. BILL 
2. ITEM
3. COMPANY

The BILL table has following columns:

```
billno,batch,product_name,qty,rate.
```

This BILL table used save sales invoice details.

The ITEM table has following column:

```
product_name,batch,qty,rate,expire_date,company_id
```

This ITEM Table used to store products that i am purchasing from a company.

The COMPANY table has following column:

```
id,name,address,cell
```

This company table used to store company details. And loaded to javafx combobox. If one is selected it automatically get the ID from COMPANY table and insert into the ITEM.COMPANY_ID.

Well, Now i needed to design a query to get the sales history from BILL table. Also As extra information i want to show that which company's product has been sold out.

Hopefully, now you guys will be able to help me out!

Comment: Sorry, did not get you! The join query should only output one row as first query without join.

Comment: Your join clause simply selects all bills with a given date, and doesn't involve any data from the company table. So for each bill that has the specified date, you get a row for each company in the table. Presumably you intended to match something from the company table to something from the bill table, in addition to matching the date?

Comment: Put another way: which company do you think the SQL statement should select?

Comment: I updated my post to explain better

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to write other JOIN condition in your ON clause.
It should contain some key that links tables (bill to company).

If you have company_id in your "bill" table and "id" in your company table query should look like below

```
select BILL.NAME as product,COMPANY.NAME AS Company,BILL.DATE as ddate,BILL.RATE as rate,BILL.QTY as quantity
FROM BILL
INNER JOIN COMPANY ON bill.company_id = company.id
WHERE BILL.DATE LIKE '%9-10-2016'
```

Comment: @rpo now I believe you should join your bills and items using on clause: `ON bill.product_name = item.product_name`. And also move your `LIKE` clause to `WHERE`

Comment: Perhaps it is working now after adding another company id in BILL.

Comment: problem not solved yet! But now i have the company_id in BILL.